# How to quantum tunnel a human?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, wavelength, quantum-tunneling

I know this is purely theoretical, but I promise it is useful to me. Please reply even if you can answer only some of the points:

1. Is the quantum tunneling probability connected to De Broglie wavelength and by increasing it somehow we could increase the probability of quantum tunneling?
2. If the molecules wavelengths' coherence is also important, would making them coherent increase the likelihood? I know that wavelengths of different molecule types in human body probably differs, but wouldn't it be enough to match the wavelengths' peaks at a certain point of time like in this [video](https://youtu.be/TQKELOE9eY4?t=171)? Also, would such action be threatening to human's life?
3. Is quantum tunneling related to the uncertainty principle and would it be possible to make human's location more "flexible" by determining their momentum with a high precision? For example by reducing it to some close to zero value?

Comment: Hello! Please only ask one question per post – otherwise it might get closed due to lack of focus. You can always [edit] your question or [ask](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a new one. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, Jonas. I structured my post with the ordinal numbers to make answering easier. I think that they are all focused on the title question. If this is not the case, I'll try to do better in future.

Comment: It would start by cooling him down to $\approx 10^{-{70}} K$. The record lowest temperature created is $\approx 10^{-9} K$. Second, the most complex lifeform capable to survive it is the [tartigrade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardigrade), there is no technology to do it with humans.